# Qt - know whether a pressed key is just a modifier

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt5.4, qkeyevent

I'd like the child's handling of `QKeyEvent` **not** to be executed when it's just a modifier key that's being pressed. The following code does the job, but it's unwieldy to list them all like that. Is there a built-in way to do that?

```
void TextEditor::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    switch(event->key())
    {
    case Qt::Key_Shift:
    case Qt::Key_Control:
    case Qt::Key_Alt:
    case Qt::Key_Meta:
    case Qt::Key_Mode_switch:
        return QPlainTextEdit::keyPressEvent(event);
    }

    // handle the event...
}
```

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer I would, if they did help me. For now, I have to leave this open.

Comment: Sorry and god luck in the search.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [QKeyEvent::modifiers()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#modifiers) member for this purpose. If the  result is

```
const bool isModifier = ( event->modifiers() != Qt::NoModifier );
```

true then the pressed key was a modifier.

So for you code it means the following modifications.

```
void TextEditor::keyPressEvent( QKeyEvent* event )
{
    if ( event->modifiers() != Qt::NoModifier )
    {
        return QPlainTextEdit::keyPressEvent(event);
    }

    // Handle the event ...
}
```

Or if you want to handle some special key combination why not just use this way:

```
void TextEditor::keyPressEvent( QKeyEvent* aKeyEvent )
{
    if ( aKeyEvent->matches( QKeySequence::Copy ) )
    {
        // Your copy stuff ...
        return;
    }
    // else if ( aKeyEvent->matches( ... ) ) // Other key combinations ...

    return QPlainTextEdit::keyPressEvent( aKeyEvent);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know about `QKeyEvent::modifiers()`, but will this also work when I hold one and press another? Also, I want to handle the key combinations like Ctrl+C normally.

Comment: In this case I think that you need another approach. Don't you want to handle the special key combinations separately ? If yes, then you can use the [QKeyEvent::matches(...)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#matches) function. I update my answer with this.

Answer (score 0):

a better way to do this in 3 lines:

```
if(event->modifiers()){
   event->ignore(); // or don't ignore and handle the event 
                    // switching the modifiers
}
```

this is the modifiers defined by qt:

```
Qt::NoModifier  
Qt::ShiftModifier   
Qt::ControlModifier
Qt::AltModifier 
Qt::MetaModifier    
Qt::KeypadModifier  
Qt::GroupSwitchModifier
```

you can do a switch for filtering.

Comment: the value of Qt::NoModifier  is 0